# Integrate Instagram API for Login with Facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

I am using social media import feature on my website. A customer comes to my website and login with Facebook or Instagram and their media details are being fetched into my system. I have created the separate app for both social media solutions.

I want to integrate Login with Facebook for Instagram media then is there any possible solution for the same? What would be the process?

I want to know that how can I add the "Login With Facebook" button the Instagram login window while opening from the API.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because Instagram API doesn't support Facebook login. If they will add it, then you can use it.